# cmd_vel(geometry_msgs::Twist) to ackermann_msgs

Tags: ros, navigation, translation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

I'd like to translate /cmd_vel(geometry_msgs::Twist) to ackermann_msgs::ackermannDrive.

Linear speed is same in two msgs.(linear.x = speed)

How can I covert angular velocity to steering angle?(angular.z --> steering_angle)

Are there nodes for it? I couldn't find to translate from angular velocity to steering angle.

Could you please let me know equation and necessary parameters?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/93531/cmd_vel(geometry_msgs::twist)-to-ackermann_msgs/) by [Park](https://answers.ros.org/users/2931/park/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-10-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex920a](https://answers.ros.org/users/14481/alex920a/) on 2014-04-28**:
any news? I need the answer too

**Comment by [macrot51](https://answers.ros.org/users/40414/macrot51/) on 2019-05-14**:
Hello Park, I try doing a similar thing. Would be glad if you could help me out. Cheers Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if you still need to know, but ...

http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node658.html

Theta_dot would be angular.z and phi is steering angle

---

Originally posted by [baronep](https://answers.ros.org/users/23631/baronep/) with karma: 106 on 2015-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1